# Can i use windows libraries in linux and vice versa?

Tags: jpeg, libraries

As per my knowledge, windows uses .lib and .dll extension for libraries and linux uses .a and .so. I am working on a project in ubuntu for manipulation with jpeg image files. so i want to know if these libraries can be used interchangeably in linux and windows? for example if have created example.so library in ubuntu and now i want to use it in some compiler in windows...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're planning on running under Wine, then yes.

Otherwise the chances are small. Windows DLLs will most probably use Windows APIs not available on Linux. Even if they're not the DLLs are built for use with compilers running on Windows.

Why not use imagemagick? http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php

Comment: More importantly, Linux libraries use gcc's .so format, while Windows libraries use actual the Windows executable format. They'll never work together.

Comment: If you're planning to go multiplatform you'll be better off thinking crossplatform anyway.

Comment: @Blindy ..and there's that. :-)

Comment: what if i'm using gcc under windows. Basically i'm working on stretch SCP board which provides its own IDE. The IDE uses gcc for compiling the C/C++ code. So in that case should i create libraries in windows or libraries created in linux will work?

Comment: Is there an update to this 10 years later? I only have .dll's on Linux, and I'm thinking about using Wine, but my Wine experience had to do with porting Wine to Solaris/MacOS or some such, and I didn't have any .dll's to mess with at the time.